# How is my Hello World assembly code not working?

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, nasm, gnu

Here is my code:

```
section .bss
    ; variables

section .data:
    ; constants

    hello: db "Hi Mom!"
    helloLen: equ $-hello

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, hello
        mov rdx, helloLen
        syscall

        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

This code is mostly from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gwYkEK0gOk&ab_channel=Fireship) youtube video by Fireship. In this he makes a simple hello world program and runs it with success.

Now when I make the same program, compile it with NASM, link it with the gnu linker (ld), and run it, it doesn't do anything. I think the problem arises from the fact that he seems to be using Linux (as that is what he normally uses) while I am using windows (11). Also, I can run the code from the vscode terminal with "./app" while I can't do the same thing with cmd. I haven't found any resources that I can really understand. I am very confused and help would be greatly appreciated. Do I maybe have to run this on Linux?

I am using:
Windows 11
NASM
GNU linker

Commands I use to compile, link, and run:
nasm -f elf64 app.asm (I have tried using win 64 with no success)
ld -o app app.o
./app (I can only run this in vscode terminal, cmd doesn't recognize prob cause it's not a .exe) IDK

Comment: Yes, this is linux code. You can make it work on windows if you use WSL. Otherwise just use a windows hello world instead.

Comment: Linux and Windows use different kinds of binary formats, PE for Windows and ELF for Linux. If not configured appropriately, you cannot execute ELFs on Windows and vice versa.
Make sure your binary has the correct format and check in which context you launch your executable (e.g. WSL or a Linux VM can run ELFs, your Windows cannot).

Comment: Even if these instructions were assembled into a Windows PE32+ executable, it would still crash because the Windows kernel doesn't interpret `syscall` with RAX=60 as `_exit`.  Like Jester said, make sure you're looking at a tutorial or example for your OS as well as architecture.  (x64 Windows; it doesn't have to be specific to Windows 11.)